# Custom Sort Multiple Files

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, awk, cat

I have 10 files (1Gb each). The contents of the files are as follows:

```
head -10 part-r-00000

a a a c b   1   
a a a dumbbell  1   
a a a f a   1   
a a a general i 2   
a a a glory 2   
a a a h d   1   
a a a h o   4   
a a a h z   1   
a a a hem hem   1   
a a a k 3
```

I need to sort the file based on the last column of each line (descending order), which is of variable length. If there is a match on the numerical value then sort alphabetically by the 2nd last column. The following BASH command works on small datasets (not complete files) and takes 3 second to sort only 10 lines from one file.

```
cat part-r-00000 | awk '{print $NF,$0}' | sort -nr | cut -f2- -d' ' > FILE
```

I want the output in a separate `FILE`. Can someone help me out to speed up the process?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for pointing out. I wrongly stated the code and have updated the statement. Coming to your second question, cat part-r-00000 gives the lines I listed below.

Comment: You don't need the `cat`; `awk` is perfectly capable of reading a file (or files).

Answer (score 2):

No, once you get rid of the UUOC that's as fast as it's going to get. Obviously you need to add the 2nd-last field to everything too, e.g. something like:

```
awk '{print $NF,$(NF-1),$0}' part-r-00000 | sort -k1,1nr -k2,2 | cut -f3- -d' '
```

Check the sort args, I always get mixed up with those..

Comment: To avoid fiddling with `sort` options, I've used `sort -n` changing the sign of the integer field... of course your solution is more general, because if the field on which the OP want a reverse sort had been non-numeric your solution would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Reverse order](http://www.unix.com/302549198-post3.html?s=95bdd1033d037a57e9ea09b4d9fd923a), sort and reverse order:

```
awk '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){printf "%s ",$i};printf "\n"}' file | sort -nr | awk '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){printf "%s ",$i};printf "\n"}'
```

Output:

```
a a a h o 4 
a a a k 3 
a a a general i 2 
a a a glory 2 
a a a h z 1 
a a a hem hem 1 
a a a dumbbell 1 
a a a h d 1 
a a a c b 1 
a a a f a 1
```

Comment: What about the OP's "If there is a match on the numerical value then sort alphabetically by the 2nd last column."?

Comment: Looping through all the fields and outputting them one at a time and then doing the whole process twice will make this command MUCH slower (I would not be surprised if it was an order of magnitude) than just prepending the line with a copy of the last fields. It will also add an undesirable blank char to the end of every line and change the white space between fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to accomplish your task,

```
awk '{print -$NF, $(NF-1), $0}' input_file | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f3-
```

1. The `awk` command prepends each record with the negative of the last field and the second last field.
2. The `sort -n` command sorts the record stream in the required order because we used the negative of the last field.
3. The `cut` command splits on spaces and cuts the first two fields, i.e., the ones we used to normalize the sort

#### Example

```
$ echo 'a a a c b   1   
a a a dumbbell  1   
a a a f a   1   
a a a general i 2   
a a a glory 2   
a a a h d   1   
a a a h o   4   
a a a h z   1   
a a a hem hem   1   
a a a k 3' | awk '{print -$NF, $(NF-1), $0}' | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f3-
a a a h o   4   
a a a k 3
a a a glory 2   
a a a general i 2   
a a a f a   1   
a a a c b   1   
a a a h d   1   
a a a dumbbell  1   
a a a hem hem   1   
a a a h z   1   
$
```

Comment: The 2nd-last field is non-numeric so what will `sort -n` do with that when the last fields are equal?

Comment: @EdMorton AFAICT, `sort -n` sorts numerically the numerical field and by usual rules what is not numeric (see the last 6 lines of the example). I confess that I didn't know what happens if part of the second(second last) fields were numeric, part non-numeric, but now I know (experimentally, that is) that the sort order is negative numbers, non-numbers sorted  "normally", positive numbers.

Comment: I don't know either and I also played around with it a bit and the only difference I saw with/without `-n` was when there was a mix of numeric/non-numeric values - then the numbers appeared first or last in the sorted order if `-n` was absent or present. I couldn't find any specs to say that's the required behavior though so I've no idea if it's just my sort (GNU) or not. Personally, I wouldn't trust it but YMMV.